# read php sensitive constant value in separated js (Jquery) file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need some help. heres the thing.
I have a PHP web project.

PHP Header file : there HTML
PHP constant file : theres some sensitive/confidential constants declared with define...

JS (Jquery) file : I need to access these sensitive/confidential constants.

How to access this constants in a way they dont get visible in html/browser (when inspecting the page) but be able to be referenced in jquery separeted file?

Comment: You can't make them accessible to JS without sending them to the browser, and if you send them to the browser, you can't make them only accessible to JS. What is it that you need to do with them? There may be a way to do it all on the server instead.

Comment: I need to read this PHP sensitive constant i.e. CLIENT_ID = 32424242 in jquery js separated file. In this js file I will post this information ,etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All JS/HTML/CSS are all loaded on user's browser. So someone can easily look into it's content and read the contant's value ( even it's on seperated JS file).

Generally sensitive information is only stored on server and once user is authenticated, sessions are used to store any sensitive information related to the authenticated user.

Comment: yep. I know the ideal is to consume the backend and work with the payload returned, but I was trying to do some quick work meanwhile backend get done. thanks a lot you all buds.